# Difference between landslide waves and earth quake waves

Tags: geophysics, seismology, seismic

I am new to this field, recently started working on landslide monitoring mainly in signal processing part. I have the following questions? 
1.Will each land slide and every vibration have p wave, s wave and surface wave ?
2.How do we segregate these three waves from the signals we would receive from our field?

Thanks in advance